# How to do a join in Oracle tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, etl

I am trying to help a co-worker do an inner join on two oracle tables so he can build a particular graph on a report.

I have no Oracle experience, only SQL Server and have gotten to what seems like the appropriate statement, but does not work.

```
SELECT concat(concat(month("a.timestamp"),','),day("a.timestamp")) as monthDay
    , min("a.data_value") as minTemp
    , max("a.data_value") as maxTemp
    , "b.forecast" as forecastTemp
    , "a.timestamp" as date
FROM table1 a
WHERE "a.category" = 'temperature'
GROUP BY concat(concat(month("timestamp"),','),day("timestamp"))
INNER JOIN (SELECT "forecast"
           , "timestamp"
        FROM table2
        WHERE "category" = 'temperature') b
ON "a.timestamp" = "b.timestamp"
```

It doesn't like my aliases for some reason. It doesn't like not having quotes for some reason.

Also when I use the fully scored names it still fails because:

```
ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended
```

Comment: move the group by to the end

Comment: and where as well

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: You've put the alias name inside the double-quotes; double-quotes indicate that the text inside should be considered as a case sensitive identifier. The correct syntax would be along the lines of: `select a."timestamp" from table1 a;`. Note that if you (for whatever reason) decided to have a case sensitive alias, you would need to double-quote that separately to any columns, e.g. `select "a"."timestamp" from table1 "a";`. If you have any control over the tables, don't create them with case sensitive identifiers; that way lies madness! *{;-)

Answer (score 1):

The order of the query should be

```
SELECT
FROM
INNER JOIN
WHERE
GROUP BY
```

as below

```
SELECT concat(concat(month("a.timestamp"),','),day("a.timestamp")) as monthDay
    , min("a.data_value") as minTemp
    , max("a.data_value") as maxTemp
    , "b.forecast" as forecastTemp
    , "a.timestamp" as date
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN (SELECT "forecast"
       , "timestamp"
      FROM table2
      WHERE "category" = 'temperature') b
ON "a.timestamp" = "b.timestamp"
WHERE "category" = 'temperature'
GROUP BY concat(concat(month("timestamp"),','),day("timestamp"))
```

Answer (score 1):

In a flood of attempts, here's yet another one.

- table2 can be moved out of subquery; join it with table1 on category as well
- note that all non-aggregates columns (from the SELECT) have to be contained in the GROUP BY clause. It seems that `a.timestamp` contains more info than just *month and day* - if that's so, it'll probably ruin the whole result set as data won't be grouped by *monthday*, but by the whole date - consider removing it from SELECT, if necessary

---

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(a.timestamp,'mm.dd') monthday,
      MIN(a.data_value) mintemp,
      MAX(a.data_value) maxtemp,
      b.forecast forecasttemp,
      a.timestamp c_date
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.timestamp = b.timestamp
             AND a.category = b.category
WHERE a.category = 'temperature'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(a.timestamp,'mm.dd'),
         b.forecast,
         a.timestamp;
```

Comment: Definitely the most idiomatic Oracle on offer

Answer (score 0):

The correct (simplified) syntax of select is

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM table1 <alias>
   JOIN table2 <alias> <join_condition>
WHERE <condition>
GROUP BY <group by columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. Use subquery:

```
SELECT c.*,  b.`forecast` as forecastTemp
FROM
(SELECT concat(concat(month(a.`timestamp`),','),day(a.`timestamp`)) as monthDay
    , min(a.`data_value`) as minTemp
    , max(a.`data_value`) as maxTemp
    , a.`timestamp` as date
FROM table1 a
WHERE `category`='temperature'
GROUP BY concat(concat(month(`timestamp`),','),day(`timestamp`))) c
INNER JOIN (SELECT `forecast`
           , `timestamp`
        FROM table2
        WHERE `category` = 'temperature') b
ON c.`timestamp` = b.`timestamp`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query should look something like this:

```
SELECT to_char(a.timestamp, 'MM-DD') as monthDay,
       min(a.data_value) as minTemp,
       max(a.data_value) as maxTemp,
       b.forecast as forecastTemp
FROM table1 a JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.timestamp = b.timestamp and b.category = 'temperature'
WHERE a.category = 'temperature'
GROUP BY to_char(timestamp, 'MM-DD'), b.forecast;
```

I'm not 100% sure this is what you want.  Your query has numerous issues and complexities:

- You don't need a subquery in the `FROM` clause.
- You can use `to_char()` instead of the more complex date string processing.
- The `group by` did not contain all the relevant fields.
- Don't use double quotes, unless really, really needed.

Comment: Presumably all of the OP's double quotes should be removed, unless one of the tables actually has columns named `"a.data_value"` etc, in which case they should be prefixed e.g. `a."a.data_value"`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the order of the components other answers have mentioned (`where` goes after `join` etc), you also need to remove all of the double-quote characters. In Oracle, these override the standard naming rules, so `"a.category"` is only valid if your table actually has a column named, literally, `"a.category"`, e.g.

```
create table demo ("a.category" varchar2(10));

insert into demo ("a.category") values ('Weird');

select d."a.category" from demo d;
```

It's quite rare to need to do this.